# Java calculating doubles - NaN

Tags: java, nan

With the code below, the variables (double) dAvgRun1, dAvgRun2 (and therefore the variable dBest) are returning as NaN when output to labels in a GUI.

What have I done wrong in my code to make my doubles NaN?

```
            double [][] daRun = new double[2][7];

            //Sets Athlete Name and Nationality labels to selected athlete in JList
            jLabel_Athlete.setText(vecAthlete.get(jList_Athlete.getSelectedIndex()).sName);
            jLabel_Country.setText(vecAthlete.get(jList_Athlete.getSelectedIndex()).sCountry);

            //Returns all scores for selected athlete
            jTextField_Run1_0.setText(vecAthlete.get(jList_Athlete.getSelectedIndex()).saTempRun1[0]);
            jTextField_Run1_1.setText(vecAthlete.get(jList_Athlete.getSelectedIndex()).saTempRun1[1]);
            jTextField_Run1_2.setText(vecAthlete.get(jList_Athlete.getSelectedIndex()).saTempRun1[2]);
            jTextField_Run1_3.setText(vecAthlete.get(jList_Athlete.getSelectedIndex()).saTempRun1[3]);
            jTextField_Run1_4.setText(vecAthlete.get(jList_Athlete.getSelectedIndex()).saTempRun1[4]);
            jTextField_Run1_5.setText(vecAthlete.get(jList_Athlete.getSelectedIndex()).saTempRun1[5]);
            jTextField_Run1_6.setText(vecAthlete.get(jList_Athlete.getSelectedIndex()).saTempRun1[6]);

            jTextField_Run2_0.setText(vecAthlete.get(jList_Athlete.getSelectedIndex()).saTempRun2[0]);
            jTextField_Run2_1.setText(vecAthlete.get(jList_Athlete.getSelectedIndex()).saTempRun2[1]);
            jTextField_Run2_2.setText(vecAthlete.get(jList_Athlete.getSelectedIndex()).saTempRun2[2]);
            jTextField_Run2_3.setText(vecAthlete.get(jList_Athlete.getSelectedIndex()).saTempRun2[3]);
            jTextField_Run2_4.setText(vecAthlete.get(jList_Athlete.getSelectedIndex()).saTempRun2[4]);
            jTextField_Run2_5.setText(vecAthlete.get(jList_Athlete.getSelectedIndex()).saTempRun2[5]);
            jTextField_Run2_6.setText(vecAthlete.get(jList_Athlete.getSelectedIndex()).saTempRun2[6]);

            //Parse all scores from string to double
            daRun[0][0] = Double.parseDouble(jTextField_Run1_0.getText());
            daRun[0][1] = Double.parseDouble(jTextField_Run1_1.getText());
            daRun[0][2] = Double.parseDouble(jTextField_Run1_2.getText());
            daRun[0][3] = Double.parseDouble(jTextField_Run1_3.getText());
            daRun[0][4] = Double.parseDouble(jTextField_Run1_4.getText());
            daRun[0][5] = Double.parseDouble(jTextField_Run1_5.getText());
            daRun[0][6] = Double.parseDouble(jTextField_Run1_6.getText());

            daRun[1][0] = Double.parseDouble(jTextField_Run2_0.getText());
            daRun[1][1] = Double.parseDouble(jTextField_Run2_1.getText());
            daRun[1][2] = Double.parseDouble(jTextField_Run2_2.getText());
            daRun[1][3] = Double.parseDouble(jTextField_Run2_3.getText());
            daRun[1][4] = Double.parseDouble(jTextField_Run2_4.getText());
            daRun[1][5] = Double.parseDouble(jTextField_Run2_5.getText());
            daRun[1][6] = Double.parseDouble(jTextField_Run2_6.getText());

            //Finds maximum and minimum scores for both runs
            int z;
            double dMinScoreRun1 = 10, dMaxScoreRun1 = 0;
            double dMinScoreRun2 = 10, dMaxScoreRun2 = 0;

            for (z=0; z<daRun.length; z++)
            {
                if (daRun[0][z] > dMaxScoreRun1)
                {dMaxScoreRun1 = daRun[0][z];}
                if (daRun[0][z] < dMinScoreRun1)
                {dMinScoreRun1 = daRun[0][z];}

                if (daRun[1][z] > dMaxScoreRun2)
                {dMaxScoreRun2 = daRun[1][z];}
                if (daRun[1][z] < dMinScoreRun2)
                {dMinScoreRun2 = daRun[1][z];}
            }


            //Calculates average scores
            double dTotalRun1 = 0, dTotalRun2 = 0;
            double dAvgRun1 = 0, dAvgRun2 = 0;

            //Run 1
            for (z=0; z<daRun.length; z++)
            {
                if(daRun[0][z] == dMaxScoreRun1 || daRun[0][z] == dMinScoreRun1)
                    continue;
                dTotalRun1 += daRun[0][z];
            }
            dAvgRun1 = dTotalRun1 / (daRun.length-2);

            //Run 2
            for (z=0; z<daRun.length; z++)
            {
                if(daRun[1][z] == dMaxScoreRun2 || daRun[1][z] == dMinScoreRun2)
                    continue;
                dTotalRun2 += daRun[1][z];
            }
            dAvgRun2 = dTotalRun2 / (daRun.length-2);

            //Displays averages for both runs
            jLabel_Average1.setText(Double.toString(dAvgRun1));
            jLabel_Average2.setText(Double.toString(dAvgRun2));

            //Compare both scores to find the best score.
            double dBest = dAvgRun1;

            if (dAvgRun2 > dAvgRun1)
            {
                dBest = dAvgRun2;
            }

            //Sets text of lblBestScore to the highest of the two scores 
            jLabel_Best.setText(Double.toString(dBest));
```

Comment: Seems like your loops are really small. I would put a break point at the beginning of your first loop after the definition of `dAvgRun1`, and debug the application. But to get NaN, you could be dividing 0.0 by 0.0.

Comment: Side note on code quality: you can not only build arrays of doubles or ints. You can also build arrays (or better Lists) of text fields. You know, it is a little bit crazy to use 12 text fields with different names to fetch values that will be stored in an array. You are repeating code 12 times, that could be condensed greatly by using an array of text fields instead.

Comment: @Jägermeister thanks for the tip. I was trying to get something like that to work with a previous iteration of this program but I couldn't wrap my head around it. I'll be sure to remember this next time I need to do something repetitive like this.

Comment: @RThomP I can only recommend: **never** duplicate code. As soon as you see yourself typing something that you just typed before; stop there; and focus on finding a solution that doesn't require to duplicate code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
double [][] daRun = new double[2][7];
```

and you use

```
dAvgRun1 = dTotalRun1 / (daRun.length-2);
```

whic will do a `dTotalRun1/0`. You may want

```
dAvgRun1 = dTotalRun1 / (daRun[0].length-2);
```

But this is also problematic. What if there's more than one value equal to minimum or maximum? You should count:

```
int cnt = 0;
for (z=0; z<daRun.length; z++){
    if(daRun[0][z] == dMaxScoreRun1 || daRun[0][z] == dMinScoreRun1)
          continue;
    dTotalRun1 += daRun[0][z];
    cnt++;
}

if( cnt != 0 ){
    dAvgRun1 = dTotalRun1 / cnt;
} else {
    // ? not sure what to use here
}
```

Comment: Winner winner chicken dinner! Thanks @laune, by making sure I used daRun[0].length wherever I previously only had daRun.length, the problem is fixed!

Comment: As for the duplicates of max or min values, yes that has been revealed as problematic in the past, although seeing as this is a university task (and such a scenario has not been specified) I'll save my efforts for now. However I'm glad you pointed it out!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies here: `for (z=0; z<daRun.length; z++)` daRun.length will return 2 instead of 7 as you might expect.